# Is it safe to use openMP simd for following loops?

Tags: c++, openmp, vectorization, simd

I am just looking more closely at OpenMP simd construct, and have three loops which seem not to be vectorized by gcc (brief performance tests), but I think that they could. So I was wondering, whether it is safe to add simd pragma and why gcc is not vectorizing them.

First is a matrix multiplication with values stored as single array:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t row = 0; row < 100; ++row){
    {#pragma omp simd}
        for(size_t col = 0; col < 100; ++col){              
            float sum = c[row * 100 + col];
            for(size_t k = 0; k < 100; k++){
                sum += a[rows * 100 + k] * b[k * 100 + col];
            }
            c[row * 100 + col] = sum;
        }
```

I am aware that b is not transposed, which hinders performance. By adding simd pragma the code gets way faster. Is auto-vectorization not possible because of the inner loop?

For the second example I was trying the custom reduction declaration feature of OpenMP, which is not actually needed.

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(sum : double : omp_out += omp_in) initializer(omp_priv = omp_orig)
double red_result = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for {simd} reduction(sum:red_result)
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i){            
        red_result = red_result + a[i];
    }
```

Does the reduction prevent vectorization? Because I would think that it should work fine?

The last example is a complex loop, with another inner loop and function calls. Simplified it looks something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for {simd}
for(size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
  [..]
  for(size_t j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    if(j != i){
      float k2 = a[i] - b[j];
       k = std::sqrt(k2);           
    }
  }
  [do more with k]
}
```

So here the problem is probably the sqrt call, which cannot be vectorized? But should the performance be better with the simd pragma? Some brief test suggests that this is the case, but if the auto-vectorization is not possible because of std::sqrt, why should it be possible with the pragma?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: FP math is not associative.  Compilers can't autovectorize FP reductions without `-ffast-math` or an OpenMP pragma that gives them permission to sum in a different order.

Comment: x86 has hardware support for SIMD sqrt.  `sqrtpd` has as good throughput as `sqrtsd` on most CPUs, but does 2 `double` square roots in parallel.  http://agner.org/optimize/.

Comment: In the past, gcc ignored simd in the case of omp parallel simd, it would be reasonable to say parallel disables vectorization (at least where simd would be needed).  The post above implies that this changed with gcc 7.1.  Even with icc, my experience was that explicit nested loops were needed to accomplish parallel simd.

Answer (score 3):

For math functions in `math.h` your compiler needs to implement vectorized versions of the math functions.  GCC does this with [libmvec](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec) and ICC does this with [SVML](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524289). As far as I know Clang does not have native support for vectorized math functions.

Let's consider the following code:

```
void foo(float * __restrict a, float * __restrict b) {    
    a = (float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16);
    b = (float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);          
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        b[i] = sqrtf(a[i]);
    }
}

void foo2(float * __restrict a, float * __restrict b) {    
    a = (float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16);
    b = (float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);          
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        b[i] = sinf(a[i]);
    }
}
```

GCC, ICC, and Clang vectorize `sqrtf` (using one iteration of Newton's method). GCC and ICC vectorize `sinf` with libmvec (`_ZGVbN4v_sinf`) and SVML (`__svml_sinf4`) respectively. Clang does not vectorize `sinf`. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BHQxFlVSCBSYphB3Eq63ZYmWIlSdKMaTQqSkFjSMyZ1DSTTe3LCMQSdRcWS0TMEHMp1MAaxAsiyBgAnAAOaF/WRjdut2RcMyydvttNSP6Z7NSXOkfNSTOCEBmUg16cp0hwWBINDaAAOjUwZAoEB3%2B4Yh5AwCyslIDnWh8XR1rpFSCiYxAAntIq6Qd117QA8iwDBfmupBYLobDns%2B%2BCBOEeBWEEz6YAAHpgyAiAQkhSD%2BjyYAwz5MtotapswbAoEWjB4Kki6QKmqC7s0qAsIuUgALQAQ4bQEAuojiJItCkemk7PnOKHtmMbFjH8qjAMgyCqC2sgVLghAkOWlbRJoqB7gexAaYJqiFrw/DViRDYgFwtAGFk7ayB2ZjQu2XDQv8XBZFwY4TlmonSAuS4riRG4wIgKA6Weh7kJQp56SAYTILQo53k0D6UKkz6viw76gT%2Bf6YIBwGgTOEGsMA0FgbB6HNIhrEzqh6GYdhuH2vhhGhMRa6kaVFEmbwVE0fA9GMXgzGsRxsi8aWAlCVIGY%2BWBYkSVJMnxaM7YGGYG0qfgRD6XI9BGeFekaVwmTGXwvBmZ1FmJRtfytmYYxZK2D33WMTleSJC1%2BUIAWrrmqabqFMXnke0VHaDKBkcAYxmMuyVYcQj7pWBmXZd%2BmZ5QVIEwZgkFldhxV4HB1VIWB9UYVhGPkC1BFgURQXQz1F0CL0A10bOw2jdIHFccEk38XQM1zVOM6LZJ0mqEopWqGMG1bRAqm7QZWkQ4eGmyGdRZXQDFlcFwBiJbQ0K0H80KyM2WSudJn3zWLP2Lsu/11mOXBffb86BddpCIUjI3Zn8QA%3D%3D%3D). `sqrt` is a special case (since the x86 instruction set has vectorized `sqrt` instructions) which can be inlined without a vectorized math library.

Comment: As you haven't declared float *__restrct c you need omp simd to assert no aliasing.  This should vectorize with simd sqrt (no Newton step) if you set appropriate options. Compilers use inline code for efficiency in such simple cases

Comment: @tim18, thanks, that's a much better solution. Now GCC, ICC, and Clang all vectorize this without OpenMP https://godbolt.org/g/Lsznwh. I think `sqrt` is a special case. If used `sin` then libmvec or SVML would be necessary.

Comment: Yes of course sqrt is special as it can use built in sqrt or Newton iteration.  The latter wouldn't make sense in svml

Comment: The case is somewhat nonsensical. Are you testing whether compilers know to eliminate the inner loop by discarding 99 results?

Comment: @tim18, I was just trying to answer the third question in the OP's question since that's the most interesting to me.  I'm not trying to eliminate the inner loop. I think `sqrt` was maybe a bad choice by the OP because it has a special solution. I think the OP wants a general answer for functions in `math.h`.

Comment: @tim18, for `sqrt` in this case `omp simd` asserts no aliasing just like in the first question by the OP `omp simd` asserts that the reduction can assume associative math. I probably have to change my answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that the most widely used compilers may be more responsive to compile options  than to omp simd for promotion of reassociation optimization.  gcc -ffast-math (not a default) or icc -fp-model fast (a default).  Optimization of sum reduction not only requires reassociation in the inner loop but may (as in the first case quoted above) require unroll-and-jam or some other reassociation of outer loops.  Of course, that is a reason for using well tested libraries for such cases rather than developing your own.

Comment: @tim18 one advantage that `omp simd` has is that if auto-vectorization is not enabled (e.g. with only `-O2` in GCC) then you can use `omp simd` to vectorize only the loops you want in the same translation unit.

Comment: I see that omp simd without -ffast-math vectorizes more frequently in gcc 8.0.1 than it used to do several years ago.  Still I have 28 cases in my test code of 130 cases which vectorize effectively with -ffast-math but don't with omp simd alone.  As far as I know, the remaining cases don't benefit from either omp simd nor ffast-math.  So I don't think this situation has changed with respect to gcc.  The tactic is more useful with icc, where the default is too aggressive with unsafe optimizations, but -fp-model source with omp simd is effective.